# Joomla 2.5 emails not received

Tags: email, joomla

I have a joomla 2.5 website that has a 3rd party extension to send a contact form.

The contact form has three email address' set up as recipients, two of them are the same as the domain ( www.domain.co.uk and info@domain.co.uk ) and the other is my email address.

I receive the email with the completed contact form however the other two address' don't receive anything.

Before I migrated this site I had the same problem, the current working email address didnt receive anything but others did. Again before site migration the domain and email address were the same.

The client has checked there junk/spam folder and the email address is currently receiving other emails.

I haven't tried SMTP yet as I would have to get the info from a client.

Any other suggestions? Do you think SMTP would resolve the issue?

Comment: What is the domain of the "from" address?

Answer (score -1):

It is mail configuration on server - many times it´s sends mails without smtp credentials to "self domain" or domains housted in same server, but not outside.

Yes smtp configuration has to resolve this issue.